# Duplicated Ionic android app not installing

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have developed android app with ionic framework and we have released in play store. After that we need a same clone of app. We duplicated that app & changed package name,app name , removed android platform and re-added  and launched in playstore.
Here I have a problem when I have first app installed from play store , second app which was released was not getting installed. Saying that

> App not installed

Only one app is getting installed. When I uninstall first app and installed second one , it is getting installed.
Following are changes I have made to duplicated app:

- Changed app name in ionic.project file
- Changed name in config.xml and also package name
- Removed android platform and re-added

Can you please help in this

Comment: please help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Did you remove the app for all "Users" ?

Settings -> Apps -> Choose your app -> Menu -> "Uninstall for all Users"

Android supports multiple users - if an app is installed from local/play store then it installs/is replicated for other users say - "Guest users" - Remove app from the device for all users then you must have it work.

Android requires an Unique Package name to be able to install in parallel

### 2. Service defined with same namespace

Another possible reason could be that "you have some services defined with same namespace" - which apparently is the issue faced by this person

### 3. Changing the package name in Build.gradle

After setting `applicationId` in build.gradle, like this:

```
android { 
defaultConfig { 
applicationId "com.your.app.here" 
...
}
```

Comment: Not only in my android mobile . For all devices , it is happening like that. Both apps are in live. I have duplicated 2nd app from first app. Changed all possible names,package names etc.

Comment: what is the package name ? - are they in public domain ?

Comment: Package namesL first app : inkakinada_app , second app  : vizageye_app. No I am running it from my local system. Do you want to provide xml, ionic.project files to check with issue

Comment: i have created a copy of first app and changed names manually. Later I have removed and added platform android for second app and uploaded in playstore

Comment: Where did you change the package name ? - Usually package name is in AndroidManifest.. Something like   <application
        android:name="com.dap.qgit.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">

Comment: Does name in  ionic.project and config.xml should be same ??

Comment: In the above package name is "com.dap.qgit.app"

Comment: I have changed in config.xml . My package name in AndroidManifest.xml is "com.ionicframework.vizageyeapp99999". I have given this manulayy based on app name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107517/discussion-between-takrishna-and-ranzit).

Comment: Thanks for your support